# Combining properties of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have an array of objects, the objects are the same but with different values. What I need is to generate a new object but concatenating the values of the same property.

This is the array:

```
interface Test {
  group: string,
  model: any
}
let dataObj: Test[] = [
  {
    "group":"car",
    "model":{
      "test":"test1",
      "data":"data1"
    }
  },
  {
    "group":"car",
    "model":{
      "test":"test2",
      "data":"data2"
    }
  }
]
```

This is what I do:

```
let result = {
  visualize: {}
}
dataObj.forEach((item: Test) => {

  const { group, model } = item

  result.visualize[group] = {
    model
  }

})
```

This is what I get:

```
{"visualize":{"car":{"model":{"test":"test2","data":"data2"}}}}
```

This is what I need:

```
{"visualize":{"car":{"model":{"test":"test1,test2","data":"data1,data2"}}}}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to add to the same group.

```js
const
    dataObj = [{ group: "car", model: { test: "test1", data: "data1" } }, { group: "car", model: { test: "test2", data: "data2" } }],
    result = { visualize: {} };

dataObj.forEach(({ group, model }) => {
    const temp = result.visualize[group] ??= {};
    Object.entries(model).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        temp[k] ??= '';
        temp[k] += (temp[k] && ',') + v;
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Array.reduce() to iterate over the dataObj array and accumulate the result in the result object.

```
let result = {
  visualize: {}
}

dataObj.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const { group, model } = item;
  if (acc[group]) {
    Object.keys(model).forEach(key => {
      acc[group].model[key] += `,${model[key]}`;
    });
  } else {
    acc[group] = { model };
  }
  return acc;
}, result.visualize);
```

And then the output should be :

```
{
  "visualize": {
    "car": {
      "model": {
        "test": "test1,test2",
        "data": "data1,data2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```